# Jenkins Matrix build. Combination filter groovy script fails after upgrade

Tags: matrix, groovy, jenkins

- Upgraded 1.599->1.605
- Matrix job is used
- In order to chooseparticular configuration or run All of them the following groovy expression is used in Combination filter:

  targetHost=="All" || targetHost.contains(hostUnderTest)

where
**hostUnderTest** is matrix axis that contains the list of available hosts
**targetHost** is build parameter and usually contains comma separated list of hosts against which tests are executed

It was working on 1.599 but fails with the following error after update to 1.605

```
FATAL: Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.String contains java.lang.CharSequence
```

I suppose these are due to some security restriction - could someone please advise how to disable them or propose another workaround?

Answer (score 2):

That is truly a pain. What version of the matrix-project do you have? You can see this through Manage Jenkins -> manage plugins

If its 1.4.1 then it is a bad release and you need to downgrade to 1.4 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/INFRA-250

I think you should be able to apply [1.4](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/matrix-project.hpi) over the top if you download it and used the advanced tab on the manage plugin page

Comment: thanks for info
after scripts are approved in **In-Process Script Approval** they are working even with 1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

According to [this comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27502?focusedCommentId=224011&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-224011) - appears to be expected behaviour.

Script works correctly after being approved by jenkins admin in

**Manage Jenkins** » **In-Process Script Approval**

menu